# adding video source selection to live stream website in node.js

Tags: node.js, angularjs, video

My website allows users to video chat with one another, but currently the only way to change the video and audio source is the built in google method. I am trying to make it easier for users to change the video and audio source of the stream - is there an easy way to add this? i am showing the video source with :

```
  <div class="show-model">
          <!--<img src="/images/img1.jpg" class="img-response" ng-hide="isStreaming">-->
          <div id="videos-container" room="{{$room}}" style="margin-top: 47px;"></div>
          <div class="fullscreen-section" ng-show="isStreaming">
            <div class="fullscreen-section__inner">
              <div class="transparent-bg"></div>
              <a class="cursor" title="full screen mode" ng-click="showFullScreen()" ng-show="!isFullScreenMode"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></a>
              <a class="cursor" title="compress screen mode" ng-click="notShowFullScreen()" ng-show="isFullScreenMode"><i class="fa fa-compress"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And here is the directive for the stream.js

```
angular.module('matroshkiApp').directive('videoPlayer', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
  return {
    template: '<div><video ng-src="{{trustSrc()}}" id="streaming-{{videoId}}" autoplay  class="img-responsive" height="130px"></video></div>',
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      vidSrc: '@',
      showControl: '@',
      vid: '@',
      muted:'='
    },
    link: function link(scope, elem, attr) {
      console.log('Initializing video-player');
      scope.videoId = scope.vid;
      scope.isMuted = scope.muted ? 'muted':'';
        if(scope.isMuted){
        jQuery(elem.context.firstChild).attr('muted',true);
         elem.context.firstChild.muted = true;
       }

      scope.trustSrc = function () {
        if (!scope.vidSrc) {
          return undefined;
        }
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(scope.vidSrc);
      };
      if (scope.showControl && elem.context && elem.context.firstChild) {
        elem.context.firstChild.controls = true;
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: No way to answer this question in any meaningful way. In your snippet of html there is no video element, so either a directive is targeting one of the classes in there or it's irrelevant. Are you just asking if there is a way to retrieve a list of available source devices so that your users can toggle between them or something, avoiding the dialog box that pops up w/ device selection that interrupts the page? An example of what I mean is how you are able to swap between front and rear cameras on a phone just by pressing a button.

Comment: Yes that is correct, another example would be a laptop and hd webcam.

Comment: I added the directive